# How to retrieve a record in a List (before insert) by VF Button

Tags: apex

I have a VF page where I can Add product with a button.

Every time I press this button in my controller I create a product and add it to a list (named productToBeAdded (without making insert) and in the VF Page I show the product's fields. When I'm satisfied I can click Final Save Button, on bottom of the page, and here my controller makes the insert of the list on the DB. I make so because before final saving I must do some checks for being sure of products'integrity. Now, the problem is that on every product created in the VF Page(before saving) there's a button for removing it,with a param. But I don't know how to retrieve the product to remove , because (being not yet inserted)  the Id of the product does not exists yet. How could I retrieve the products to be removed and delete it from the list before final saving?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can introduce unique id and set it to another field in your `productToBeAdded` wrapper. Then check for that Id in the controller

Comment: but how can I get the element in a list with a particular field value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a blog that walks you through what you are trying to accomplish using a wrapper class:
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/managing-list-of-new-records-in.html?m=1